# Get Jetty Sever instance by host and port

Tags: jetty

Is it possible to get [Server](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.1.4.v20140401/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html) instance by **host** and **port**?

Comment: InetSocketAddress is there. Doesn't work ?

Comment: Well, I can create Server by passing the InetSocketAddress as a constructor's parameter. But I need API for getting Server instance (if exists / running) by host and port combo.